# Does Simulating mdadm failure require rebuilding entire Array? mdadm -manage -set-faulty

Tags: raid, mdadm, software-raid, testing

[Based on this article](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Detecting,_querying_and_testing#Force-fail_by_software) and a few similar others I see how to simulate a mdadm failure, but it seems it's going to require a rebuild of my array.

I don't want to give it that much IO and also it took days for me to add a disk to the array last time.

**Can anybody confirm if the following requires a rebuild of array, or if mdadm will just come back online?**

```
mdadm -manage -set-faulty /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sda1
mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sdc2
```

"This could be a degraded RAID or perhaps a system in the middle of a reconstruction process. We wait until recovery ends before setting things back to normal." -- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Software-RAID-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: You can always experiment using loop devices.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device and http://wiki.osdev.org/Loopback_Device for some reference material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove a disk from the array; the array needs rebuilding when it's re-added.  The rebuild is automatic, but can take time.

However the rebuild time can be minimised if you have a *write intent bitmap* set on the volume.  If the number of changes are small enough then when the disk is re-added it will effectively do a recovery by bringing the "stale" disk back up to date.  This can change a rebuild from being hours down to seconds.

See https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Write-intent_bitmap for details.

Comment: Seems like my best option, thank you, I will test and accept!